# reCaptcha error-callback stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

So I am using an invisible reCaptcha on my page, and I am using the `error-callback` function to report errors to the users. Trouble is, whenever the error-callback is hit, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. I am triggering the "error" by forcing the sitekey to be incorrect, I am not sure if this is related or not, but I need a good way of forcing the recaptcha to hit this callback for testing and development purposes.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbpmd0y5/

And this is the sample code I am using to diagnose the problem:

```
<div id="cResults"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitHandler() {
    var captchaTarget = 'cResults'
    var shareCaptcha = window.grecaptcha.render(captchaTarget, {
      sitekey: 'sitekey',
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: function(token) {},
      'error-callback': function() {
        console.log('error');
        window.grecaptcha.reset(shareCaptcha);
      }
    });
    window.grecaptcha.execute(shareCaptcha);

  }
</script>

<button value="go" onclick="submitHandler()">Go</button>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?" async defer></script>
```

If you run this code, you will see that the recaptcha box in the bottom right corner will flash continuously (like its reloading) and if you open the console, you will see an infinite stream of `error` messages.

*Any ideas?*

Answer (score 0):

*Solved.*

The problem seemed to be that I was calling `grecaptcha.reset()` from within the `error-callback`, which was causing the error to be caught over and over.

Here is a working fiddle with the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/w6m3caxq/

And the final, working code sample:

```
<div id="cResults"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitHandler() {
    var captchaTarget = 'cResults'
    var shareCaptcha = window.grecaptcha.render(captchaTarget, {
      sitekey: 'sitekey',
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: function(token) {},
      'error-callback': function() {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
    window.grecaptcha.execute(shareCaptcha);

  }
</script>

<button value="go" onclick="submitHandler()">Go</button>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?" async defer></script>
```

Hopefully this can help someone from banging their head against the wall.

Comment: how does this code help reset recaptcha?

Comment: @Alexy This code does not help reset reCaptcha. To do that you would just need to call `window.grecaptcha.reset()`, my code was stuck in an infinite loop because I was calling `grecaptcha.reset` from within the error callback, so if an error triggered, it would reset the captcha, and if the error persists, it would keep calling the error callback.